# Test failing using Moq and Timer

Tags: c#, multithreading, unit-testing, moq, mstest

I have the following test case:

```
private static readonlystring TEST_KEY = "SomeKey";
private static readonly object TEST_VALUE = 2;
private static readonlyTimeSpan TEST_EXPIRATION = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2);

[TestMethod]
public void SetMethodStoresValueForCorrectTime()
{
    Mock<ObjectCache> mock = new Mock<ObjectCache>();

    // Setup mock's Set method
    mock.Setup(m => m.Set(TEST_KEY, TEST_VALUE, It.IsAny<DateTimeOffset>(), It.IsAny<string>()))
    .Callback(() => mock.Setup(m => m.Get(TEST_KEY, It.IsAny<string>())).Returns(TEST_VALUE));

    MyCache<object> instance = new MyCache<object>(mock.Object);

    // Add value to mocked cache
    instance.Set(TEST_KEY, TEST_VALUE, TEST_EXPIRATION);
    Assert.AreEqual(TEST_VALUE, instance.Get(TEST_KEY));

    // Configure a timer for item's expiration (Make mock's Get method return null)
    Timer timer = new Timer(_ => mock.Setup(m => m.Get(TEST_KEY, It.IsAny<string>())).Returns(null), null, TEST_EXPIRATION.Milliseconds, -1);

    // Wait for TimerCallback to trigger
    Thread.Sleep(TEST_EXPIRATION.Add(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)));
    Assert.IsNull(instance.Get(TEST_KEY)); // <-- Failing here

    timer.Dispose();
}
```

And here is `MyCache<T>` (the relevant part of it):

```
public class MyCache<TSource> : ICache<TSource>
{
     private ObjectCache _innerCache;

     public MyCache(System.Runtime.Caching.ObjectCache innerCache)
     {
         _innerCache = innerCache;
     }

     // ...

     public TSource Get(string key)
     {
         if (key == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("key");
         object value = _innerCache.Get(key);
         return value != null ? (TSource)value : default(TSource);
     }

     public void Set(string key, TSource value, TimeSpan expiration)
     {
         if (key == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("key");
         _innerCache.Set(key, value, DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.Add(expiration));
     }
}
```

Why is the test failing?
It is failing on the last assertion:

> **Assert.IsNull** failed.

Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: Why are you creating a timer and not using it (except disposing it)?

Comment: @JeroenHeier It should start automatically after `TEST_EXPIRATION.Milliseconds` milliseconds

Answer (score 0):

I copied your code and the test passes on my machine.

However you should probably rethink your test, as you're trying to test MyCache which is simply wrapping ObjectCache.  You don't need to test the cache expiration (since this is part of ObjectCache, and should be part of its unit tests) but just that MyCache correctly delegates the Get and Set operations to ObjectCache.  For example:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void SetMethodStoresValueInInnerCache()
    {
        Mock<ObjectCache> mock = new Mock<ObjectCache>();

        MyCache<object> instance = new MyCache<object>(mock.Object);

        // Add value to mocked cache
        instance.Set(TEST_KEY, TEST_VALUE, TEST_EXPIRATION);

        mock.Verify(x => x.Set(TEST_KEY, TEST_VALUE, It.IsAny<DateTimeOffset>(), It.IsAny<string>()), Times.Once);
    }
```

You could have an equivalent for the Get.
If you want to test that MyCache is setting the expiration properly (the code `DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.Add(expiration)`), then you could create an interface like `ITime` and use `time.UtcNow` (where time is an injected instance of `ITime`) in your code - the real implementation would return `DateTime.UtcNow` and in your unit test you could mock it with a fixed time (and then assert that the expiration was that fixed time plus TEST_EXPIRATION)